# How to update user email field in firebase using web?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working with mobile developer.

As they are creating new user in mobile application, they register the user on firebase also.

Mobile application also has Admin section where I can edit the user information.
Now I have a requirement that while I am updating any user information, I also need to update the user email field on firebase also.

Is there any way to update the field of user on firebase?

I searched a lot and got the way how to add the reference to firebase on web but am not able to update user field.

**Code**

Given reference on cshtml page of firebase

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

---

This code i have added in jquery file. Configuration is replace for security purpose.

```
 var config = {
                        apiKey: "Apikey",
                        authDomain: "domainname",
                        databaseURL: "given db url",
                        projectId: "ProjectId",
                        storageBucket: "storageBucket",
                        messagingSenderId: "000000"
                    };
                    firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

**This is used for firebase database reference as got from the google doc.**

```
 var firebaseRefs = firebase.database().ref();
```

**This is the code i am using for updating email field in firebase users node**

```
var uid = '';
                firebase
               .auth()
               .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.Email, data.Password)
               .then(function () {
                   auth = user;
                  firebaseRefs.ref("users/" + data.Id).update({ email: data.Email});
               .catch(function (error) {
                   console.log("Login Failed!", error);
               });
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to interact with Firebase.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. - @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `updateEmail()` method of the JavaScript SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateEmail), but, if I am not mistaking, you should be authenticated as the user itself.

---

You can also update a User (including the email) through the Admin SDK, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user.

In this case you don’t need to be authenticated as the user.

You should use this SDK from a managed environment, for example Cloud Functions, but it can be from your server too.

If you want to use this method from the web you could call, from your web front-end, an HTTP Cloud Function (or a callable one, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

---

Following your update, you could do as follows:

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.Email, data.Password)
    .then(function (userCredential) {
         var user = userCredential.user;
         return user.updateEmail(data.Email);
    })
    .then(function () {
         return firebaseRefs.ref("users/" + data.Id).update({ email: data.Email});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
         console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    });
```

Note that `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential), from which you get the `user`, see 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: Thanks @Renaud. I am using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword() method to authenticate the user but not getting successfully authenticated.

Comment: You should share your **entire** code if you want the community to help you.

Comment: Sure, @Renaud Tarnec.